# RTSP (video stream) in Electron

Tags: electron, rtsp

I've installed `fluent-ffmpeg` and `ffmpeg-static` to convert a stream into an HTML reproducible video. How can I use these packages to display the stream in the client?

Server side (**`main.js`**):

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const ffmpeg                 = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpegPath             = require('ffmpeg-static').replace('app.asar', 'app.asar.unpacked');

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

function createWindow () {
    
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    win.loadFile('index.html');
}

function testStream () {
    
   let source = 'rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov';

    
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow).then(testStream);
```

Client side (**`index.html`**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = 'UTF-8'>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>I want to reproduce the video here</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly; you're probably looking to start with something like this:

```
    <video id="video-player" controls preload="none" style="border: 5px solid red; height: 1080px; width: 1920px; ">
        <source src="index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    </video>
```